# Nuvoton NUC120 Communication via Build in USB

Tags: serial-port, arm

I just bough NUC120, and there is nothing less than expected. What sparked my interest is, as stated on page 17-18 on the datasheet, It able to do UART communication. So far, I only use the USB port to uploading the firmware via ISP using NuMicro ISP Programming Tools. I've noticed (correct me if I'm wrong) that its the same concept with Arduino boards, where the USB port can be used to both programming and communication. I have do my research for several days, but still can't find how to do serial communication between Nuvoton and PC, since when I do programming using NuMicro, I use "USB" connection type, and on my PC, there is no COM PORT listed.

My question, Is it possible to do serial communication via Nuvoton USB port? If its possible, can you please point me where to look?

Thanks in advance. Please tell if I should add more details about this question.

Comment: It's possible to do *"serial communications"* over USB using CDC/ACM.  But that is not 100% equivalent to using a UART.  E.G. USB CDC/ACM is not practical for debugging early boot issues.  There is no simple replacement for a full-duplex communication link that a UART provides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the examples in the [BSP documentation](http://www.nuvoton.com/opencms/resource-download.jsp?tp_GUID=SW0720100830110430). Look for samples of USBD_VCOM. To be able to communicate with your PC, you have to install the driver of Virtual COM manually